# Vue countdown event at end

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the countdown [vuejs-countdown](https://github.com/getanwar/vuejs-countdown) in my vue component and I would like to show another component at the end of the countdown.

Something like:

```
   <template>
     <div>
         <flip-countdown :deadline=element.deadline></flip-countdown>
         <div v-if="!element.deadline"> Expired!</div>
      </div>
   </template>
```

But I don't know if an end event exists for this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing any events being emitted in the library, you can see the component here: https://github.com/getanwar/vuejs-countdown/blob/master/src/Countdown.vue

however, you could edit the component and add a custom 'end' event by adding a simple `$emit('end')` to the code of that component on line `83` like below

```
if(this.diff <= 0 || this.stop) {
  this.diff = 0;
  // Remove interval
  clearInterval(interval);
  this.$emit('end') // emitting our custom end event
}
```

then you could use that event to set a Boolean to true once the countdown has ended:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <flip-countdown :deadline='element.deadline' @end='expired = true'></flip-countdown>
    <div v-if="!expired"> Expired!</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. Any other suggestions in case of more countdowns on same page?

Comment: you could use an object to keep track of all the various countdowns that you set as data e.g. `countdownStates: {  countdown1Expired: false, countdown2Expired: false }` and then reference them as in the example above so that you can check for each countdown expiration state individually.